# nullif(0, '') returns null

Tags: mysql, triggers, nullif

I have a trigger that should convert empty strings to `null` for a `tinyint(1)` boolean column:

```
CREATE TRIGGER convertToNull
BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
SET new.myBoolean = nullif(new.myBoolean, '');
```

The problem is, it also converts `0` to `null`.

I checked with:

```
mysql> select nullif(0, '');
+---------------+
| nullif(0, '') |
+---------------+
|          NULL |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How to make `nullif` stricter, such that ONLY empty strings will be converted to `null`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? A tinyint is never `''`

Comment: I want the tinyint to be either 0, 1 or NULL. So I'm attempting to convert empty strings to NULL when inserting rows from a tsv file.

Comment: but it will never be an empty string. By the time the trigger fires, the conversion from blank to `0` will have already happened. What you're attempting can't done.,

Comment: Oh I see, I was under the impression triggers fired before mysql did anything.